# Suggestion on simple Regex or Boundary Extractor

Tags: jmeter

Please could you help me extract the below number 3 from the response:

href="/invoices/matrix?page=3">Next

I tried the below without any success:

1. Boundary Extractor (getting many matches although the boundaries are correct)
   Right Boundary: href="/invoices/matrix?page=  Left Boundary: ">Next
2. RegEx : href="/invoices/matrix?page=(.*?)"Next

Thanks,
Nags

Answer (score 0):

1. Regular Expression:

   ```
   href="/invoices/matrix\?page=(\d+)">Next
   ```

   [image]
2. Boundary Extractor:

   - left boundary: `href="/invoices/matrix?page=`
   - right boundary: `">Next`

   [image]

More information:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter)